# jQuery Validation - Criteria Required But Also a Warning

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a web page whose only input is a PO.  They must enter the PO and it must contain letters, numbers, dashes, underscores and/or periods and must be between 2 and 15 characters long.  I believe I have all of that working with the code I inherited (I am new to jQuery).

However, if all of those tests pass, I also need to do a remote test against our database to see if the user's company has already used that PO.  If they have, I need to warn them and give them the option to either enter a different value or submit the value as entered.  This is where I am stuck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.validator.addMethod("noSpecialChars", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Ignored");

jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
$("#form1").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'PO must contain only letters, numbers, dashed, underscores or periods and must be between 2 and 15 characters long.'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
            $("div.productError span").html(message);
            $("div.productError").show();
        } else {
            $("div.productError").hide();
        }
    },

    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("div.productError").hide();
        form.submit();
    },

    rules: {
        po_number: {
            required: true,
            noSpecialChars: true,
            rangelength:[2,15]
        }
    },

    messages: {
        po_number: {
            required: 'blah',
            noSpecialChars: 'blah',
            rangelength: 'blah'
        }
    },
    debug:true
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Much clearer to me now.

Considering your comments and reading a little in the documentation, I'd recommend invoking a second validation on the form in the `.submitHandler`.

Looking at the documentation, that callback is called only if the form actually is valid, that is after your checks return true. Then, before submitting your form, you can perform another check and if that returns true as well, submit the form. Else popup whatever you need to say to your clients.

From the doc:

> Callback for handling the actual submit **when the form is valid**. Gets the form as the only argument. **Replaces the default submit**. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

The second bold part makes me a little doubtful about your code... you seem to re-submit your form again, thus passing it in for another validation. Maybe I got that part wrong. If so, I apologize.

Comment: I understand that I need to do a remote rule.  What I do not understand is how do I get the validate to run a first pass that does the required logic (what I have above) and if that passes, then run a 2nd (nested?) validate to do the remote test, and if it fails (the PO # already exists), pop up a box warning them with the ability to retry or continue.  The issue is having a sub-validate (or whatever).

Comment: @user1588106 Notifying you about a change of my answer. I believe the system else wouldn't notify you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery validator plugin, then you can easily use the [remote method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) to do so

Comment: Maybe it is because I am a noob to jQuery, but how do I do required tests (which it now does) and if they all pass, THEN AND ONLY THEN do a conditional remote test?  I do not want the remote test to fire off unless the required tests all pass.  Its the conditional firing off of a 2nd, sub-validation that has me scratching my head.